# Completeness of $l_1 ^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to prove that $l_p ^\infty $ is complete for each $p\geq 1$ but only with the definition of $\varepsilon$-$N$.

I know that this have been proved in other posts here but I couldn't find a proof with the $\varepsilon$-$N$ method only.

Here is my try for $p=1$:

let $\{x^{(n)}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $l_1 ^\infty$. Then it is easy to show that for each fixed $i\in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $\{x_i ^{(n)}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to some $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$.

Now it is left to show that the vector $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ is in $l_1 ^\infty$ and that $x^{(n)}\longrightarrow x$.

This is the part where I can't prove only by the $\varepsilon$-$N$ method.

I know that for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$, I can define $N=\max \{N_i |1\leq i\leq k\}$

such that $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1} ^k}|x_i ^{(n)} -x_i|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

What most of the proofs I saw do now is to take $k\longrightarrow \infty$ to get: $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1} ^\infty}|x_i ^{(n)} -x_i|\leq\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

The problem with this is that $N$ depends on $k$ which means that $n$ can't be held constant when $k\longrightarrow \infty$. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please define what $l_1^\infty$ is?

Comment: $l_1 ^\infty$ is the normed space of all real sequences with finite $l_1$-norm

Comment: Ok.  Most people simply call this $l_1$ or $l^1$.  I didn't understand why the $\infty$ was there.

Comment: just because in my course we differentiate between this normed space and the $l_p ^n$ normed space which is the normed space of all real n-tuples

Comment: You should write $ l_p $ or $ l^p$ only, (which is standard), as $l^{\infty}$ or $l_{\infty}$  is used for the space of bounded sequences  $(x_n)_n$ with norm $\|(x_n)_n\|_{\infty}=\sup_n |x_n|.$

Answer (score 0):

Once we have found the coordinstewise limit, we have to go back to the $\ell^1$-norm. For each positive $\varepsilon$, there exists an integer $N$ such that if $m,n\geqslant N$, then 
$$\left\lVert x^{(m)}-x^{(n)}\right\rVert_1=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} 
\left\lvert x_i^{(m)}-x_i^{(n)}\right\rvert
\lt \varepsilon.$$
In particular, for *any* $k$, 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k} 
\left\lvert x_i^{(m)}-x_i^{(n)}\right\rvert
\lt \varepsilon
$$
provided that $m,n\geqslant N$. So $N$ does not depend on $k$.